# POST, Response and assertJson in phpunit testing

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have following test function to check the update data is correct or not.
It has no problem in updating.
My question is how to check the given parameters are correct after updated.

for example

```php
if response.id == 1 and response.name = 'Mr.Smith'
    assertcode = OK
else 
    assertcode = NG
```

```php
public function user_update_info(){
        $this->post('login',['email' => config('my-app.test_user'),
            'password' => config('my-app.test_pass')]);
        $response = $this->post('/update_info',[
            'id'                => 1,
            'name'              => 'Mr.Smith',
            'post_code'         => '142-4756',
            'prefectural_code'  => '15',
            'address'           => 'Merchat St.',]);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want to confirm what is in the json response or you want to check if the data is saved correctly into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your `update_info` route update `User` model.

Try below after your code,

```
$user = User::find(1);
static::assertTrue($user->id == 1 && $user->name = 'Mr.Smith');
```

To check if the response returns a json data you expect, you can use `assertJson()` method of the response object like so:

```
$response->assertJson([
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'Mr.Smith'
]);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't say how to tests json response. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin I agree with you. Since the question is asking for assertJson, I think it's not answering his question.

Comment: My answer is not very accurate. I have the same question as @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin. It can check if the data is saved correctly into the database. If want  assertJson please see https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/http-tests#testing-json-apis

Comment: I think the OP's question also is ambiguous in the sense that it appears as though it is requesting for assertJson or assertDatabaseHas. I could see that this answer is already accepted, therefore it seems as though the OP wants to see if the data is persisted in the database, therefore makes this answer correct. I will make an update to the answer if you don't mind @liquid207

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin That's what i've thinking too. Since the OP has already accepted the answer, I can't fully blame `@liquid207` for his answer.

Comment: @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin Thanks.